# Cannot pass queryParams

Tags: ember.js

I'm newbie in ember.js and i'm trying to sort a list of products in my app.

I have a route `catalog/category.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    ordering: {
      refreshModel: false,
    },
  },
  model (params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      categories: this.store.peekAll('category'),
      category: this.store.peekRecord('category', params.category_id),
    });
  }
});
```

and controller `catalog/category.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['ordering'],
  ordering: null,
  sortedProducts: Ember.computed.sort('model.category.products', 'ordering'),
});
```

Link passes a parameter:

```
{{#link-to 'catalog.category' (query-params ordering='price')}}Price Asc{{/link-to}}
```

`ordering` parameter is setting to `price` and it doesn't work. But when I manually set the `ordering` parameter to `['price']` - everything works as expected.

Can anyone suggest how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ordering parameter is setting to price and it doesn't work. But when I
>   manually set the ordering parameter to ['price'] - everything works as
>   expected.

There is a difference between `string:price` (set by query param) and `array:['price']` (set by you manually).

You need another property which will create that array for you:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['ordering'],
  ordering: null,
  orderingObserver: Ember.on('init', Ember.observer('ordering', function() {
    let ordering = this.get('ordering');
    let array = [];
    if (ordering) {
      array.push(ordering);
    }
    this.set('orderingArray', array);
  })),
  sortedProducts: Ember.computed.sort('model.category.products', 'orderingArray'),
});
```

> isn't it supposed to work "out of the box"?

It works with arrays of properties - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Ember Inspector reports that the orderingArray equals 'price'.

Comment: Answer updated - try `this.set('orderingArray', array);` instead. I guess it isn't.